# What's the best way to get this table into the desired format?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access.

I have a query that looks like this:

> **item**,**unit_of_measure**,**uom_size**
>
> soda,each,1
>
> soda,pack,6
>
> soda,case,12
>
> candybar,each,1
>
> gum,pack,1
>
> gum,case,4

And so on, for 20,000+ entries. Each **item** may have multiple **units of measure**, which each have their own **size**. No item has the same unit_of_measure twice. No item in this table has more than 3 units of measure.

My goal is to create a query to take the information in this table and render it in the format below:

> **item, uom_1, uom_2, uom_3, uom_1_size, uom_2_size, uom_3_size**
>
> soda, each, pack, case, 1, 6, 12
>
> candybar, each, null, null, 1, null, null
>
> gum, pack, case, null, 1, 4, null

In short, I want each **item** on its own row, and each distinct **unit_of_measure** in a uom_* column, ascending by the **uom_size**. If an item contains does not contain all three, a null value is ideal.

(I know that final goal table is wonky. It must be that way to mimic a view in my company's esoteric RDBMS, so that I can easily compare them.)

I've spent hours looking for a solution. The furthest I could think was to create a triple series of MIN(uom_size) queries... but I feel like I'm overthinking this and am simply ignorant of a more efficient solution. This is a small piece of a larger project and I do not want to overdevelop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

All you need to do is this. First of all you will need to create a counter for each group. You will need to make the `unit_of_measure` in each of the groups have a counter assigned, like this:

[image: Query with Counter]

```
ID  item    unit_of_measure uom_size    grp
----------------------------------------------
1   soda        each            1       Group1
2   soda        pack            6       Group2
3   soda        case            12      Group3
4   candybar    each            1       Group1
5   gum         pack            1       Group1
6   gum         case            4       Group2
```

There are different ways to achieve this. The easiest way to do is to create a new query and use the `DCount()` function, like this (I used the name Table3 as the source, you will need to rename it to the name of your initial query):

```
SELECT 
Table3.ID, 
Table3.item, 
Table3.unit_of_measure, 
Table3.uom_size, 
"Group" & CStr(DCount("*","Table3","item='" & [item] & "' and uom_size <= " & CStr([uom_size]))) AS grp
FROM Table3;
```

Save this as a new query. I have saved it as `Query3`. Now, all you need to do is to create a couple of crosstab queries (one for the `uom`, and another for the `uom_size`):

**Query3_Crosstab_uom**

```
TRANSFORM Max(Query3.unit_of_measure) AS MaxOfunit_of_measure
SELECT Query3.item
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.item
PIVOT Query3.grp;
```

**Query3_Crosstab_uom_size**

```
TRANSFORM Max(Query3.uom_size) AS MaxOfuom_size
SELECT Query3.item
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.item
PIVOT Query3.grp;
```

And finally, all you need to do is to join the two above queries:

```
SELECT Query3_Crosstab_uom.item, Query3_Crosstab_uom.Group1, 
Query3_Crosstab_uom.Group2, Query3_Crosstab_uom.Group3, 
Query3_Crosstab_uom_size.Group1, Query3_Crosstab_uom_size.Group2, 
Query3_Crosstab_uom_size.Group3
FROM Query3_Crosstab_uom INNER JOIN Query3_Crosstab_uom_size 
ON Query3_Crosstab_uom.item = Query3_Crosstab_uom_size.item;
```

And the result is:

[image: the final result]

```
item        Group1  Group2  Group3  Group1 Group2 Group3
--------------------------------------------------------
candybar    each                    1       
gum         pack    case            1       4   
soda        each    pack    case    1       6       12
```